# Android TextView Number Animation

Tags: android, animation, textview, numbers, textchanged

I have a textview with numbers in it. If the number was changed, i want to animate this. But this shouldn't be a fade in and fade out effect. I want to animate every single number with a vertical flip effect. Is that possible?

Comment: what do you mean by `vertical flip effect`?

Comment: i mean that the old number will disappear upwards and the new number come from below

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/ see this i think your need is `Slide Up`

Answer (score 0):

`Animation` in Android is used by **Views**.

So, `TextView` will make animation at whole.

If you want to make animation for each single number then create a lot of `TextView` as number digits (programmatically) and move the digits from the original `TextView` to each `TextView`. Then make animation to all these `TextViews`.

If the original `TextView` has the content **(301)**, then you should create three `TextView` and set the **'3'** as text to the first `TextView` and set **'0'** to the second , and so on.

Comment: Thank you. Thats very ugly but if there is no other solution i have to do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for odometer like effect, there are two tutorials and code samples I know of that can help you, BUT you will need to do a custom view to achieve this effect:

http://kevindion.com/2010/12/android-odometer-ui-tutorial-part-2/
https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-FlipDigitView

This is the video of the final animation of second tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6-M2nN2Gzg&feature=youtu.be